# Remember the session with Auth module?

Tags: php, authentication, module, kohana

I'm trying to make the Auth module to 'remember' the user session with a checkbox on the login page. What happens is that no cookie is created, only session as usually. I've noticed the user_tokens table, but don't see any use of user_token model's methods at all. I do pass `(bool) TRUE` as a third parameter to `login()` method, but there's no difference.

Is this feature complete at all or I have to add my own by overwritting the `login()` method of Model_Auth_User ?

What's the best practice for this ?

- I also opened [a topic on Kohana Forums](http://forum.kohanaphp.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=4817&page=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Answer from the Kohana forum (credit to biakavero)](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/34309#Comment_34309) pasted here for reference:

1. Call `Auth::instance()->login()` with `$remember = TRUE`
2. DB Token for current user created. Cookie `authautologin` generated.
3. Destroy user object : `Session::instance()->delete('auth_user'); // dont call logout() method as it will delete cookie & token`
4. Call `Auth::instance()->auto_login()` and check for `Auth::instance()->get_user() // should return Model_User object`

Comment: any idea why this wouldn't work on a page that is $_POSTed to with flash (swfupload)?

Comment: @handsomeGun because swfupload doesn't send the cookie for the session. You'll need to pass it some other way and possibly grab it in your script and load the session using the passed key.